# Inconsistency with Quartz Drawing on OSX vs. iOS

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, drawrect

I implemented a `drawRect:` callback on an `NSView` for the purpose of drawing realtime waveforms from the microphone on my mac.  I would call `setNeedsDisplay:Yes` from an NSTimer rapidly and this `drawRect:` code resulted in a very smooth rendering of some number of bandlines fluctuating to the microphone input.  (I am dumping raw audio data into an array property of my audio object singleton which the NSView is using for draw calls.  This question is about drawing and not the data).  Here is the Cocoa code which results in a smooth drawing once every 0.01 seconds:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

   NSBezierPath *bez = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];

   float startingX = 0;
   float numOfBandLines = 1024;

   float spectralWidth = self.bounds.size.width / numOfBandLines;

   for (int i = 0; i < numOfBandLines; i++) {

      CGFloat sampleValue = [SineWavePlayer sharedInstance].amplitude.values[i];

      float yPos = alexMap(sampleValue, 0, 1, 0, self.bounds.size.height);


      [bez moveToPoint:CGPointMake(startingX, 0)];
      [bez lineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingX, yPos)];

      startingX += spectralWidth;
   }

   NSColor * color = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedHue:1 saturation:1 brightness:1 alpha:1];

   [color set];
   [bez setLineWidth:1];
   [bez stroke];

 }
```

However, when trying to port this to iOS, the drawing overlaps itself each call.  So after a few seconds there are multiple band lines where there should be one band line adjusting every 0.01 seconds.  (the behavior in Cocoa).  (This code has only one line thats being successively drawn based on the data in the zero'th array element for simplicity's sake):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   [super drawRect:rect];

   UIBezierPath *bez = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];


   CGFloat sampleValue = alexMap([MicController sharedInstance].amplitude.values[0], 0, 1, 0, 100);


   [bez moveToPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50)];
   [bez addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100 + sampleValue)];


   UIColor * color = [UIColor redColor];

   [color set];
   [bez setLineWidth:1];
   [bez stroke];

}
```

It seems that essentially the same code is producing different behaviors on the different OS's.  Is there some reason for this?

Comment: Is `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` set to NO on your `UIView` subclass?

Comment: It was not.  I added `self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;` and made the background color non-nil and I got the same behavior as Cocoa.  Leading into the question, does Cocoa do this by default?  Too bad, you didn't post and answer so I could accept it.